# Changing the date format in r with strptime and as.Date

Tags: r, date, strptime, as.date

Following is part of my data:

```
       Date        Elev Temp.C 
1 02 January 2010  200   14.7
2 02 January 2010  300    5
3 02 January 2010  500    -2
4 02 January 2010 1000   -9.8
5 02 January 2010 2000   -7.1
```

I wanted to change the format of the date in to `2010-01-01` or `"%Y-%m-%d"`. Class of `data` is `character` and I tried as follows:

```
data$Date<-as.Date(data$Date,format="%d%B%Y")

data$Date<-as.Date(data[["Date"]],"%d%B%Y")

data$Date<-strptime(data$Date,"%d%B%Y")
```

All of the above trials are displaying `<NA>`in the Date column. I have another data file with date format of `"%m/%d/%Y"`, it worked fine with `strptime`, but for the above data set it is not working. Any idea?

Comment: @Zheyuan Li what do you mean `%B` is sensitive?

Comment: @ Zheyuan Li "English_United States.1252"

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I got ` "2016-03-02"`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi but when I tried with my data it didn't work.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I already tried to with my actual data but it didn't work. I am still getting `NA`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi . Yes, the space was the problem. I didn't leave space, so that was the cause of the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @ZhenyuanLi Go ahead, you can put it with description! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to your locale. If you look at `?strptime`, you will see:

```
 ‘%B’ Full month name in the current locale.  (Also matches
      abbreviated name on input.)
```

This means, `%B` is sensitive to your locale. Have a look at `?locales` if you are unsure what a locale is. When I asked you about the output of `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")`, you said you got `"English_United States.1252"`. Now let's first change your locale:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
```

Then do:

```
as.Date("02 January 2010", "%d %B %Y")
# [1] "2010-01-02"
```

Note, since there is an empty space between "02", "January" and "2010", you need to leave an empty space between `%d`, `%B`, `%Y`. So, don't use `"%d%B%Y"` as put in your post, but use `"%d %B %Y"`.